# Dojo CheckedMultiSelect text wrap and horizontal scrolling

Tags: dojo

How to make DOJO CheckedMultiSelect text wrapped and how to enable horizontal scrolling in the same control, if the select text is larger that the control size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to overwrite CSS rules. See working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/qrSWu/

**For both** of your needs you need to limit the `width` of `dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect`. It can be done adding `narrow` class to the markup `<select data-dojo-type="dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect" class="narrow">` or JavaScript (via `className`):

```
.narrow .dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper {
    width: 100px;
}
```

For **horizontal scrolling** add also `scroll` class (`class="narrow scroll"`):

```
.scroll .dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

For **wrapping** the option text add `wrap` class (`class="narrow wrap"`):

```
.wrap .dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel {
    white-space: normal;
}

.wrap .dojoxMultiSelectItemBox {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Depending on the order you include stylesheets you may need to add `!important`.