# How to set width to dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have this following code in dojo which is using dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect:

```
var checkedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect ({
    id:"something",
    dropDown: true,
    multiple: true,
    labelText:"something",
    store: dataStore,
    style : {width:"240px"} // this doesn't work
}, "placeholder");
```

How do I set a width to this widget?

I use dojo 1.9

Comment: Have you tried applying the styles to #placeholder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/qrSWu/

stolen from this post:

[Dojo CheckedMultiSelect text wrap and horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673582/dojo-checkedmultiselect-text-wrap-and-horizontal-scrolling)

You have to overwrite some css styles...

```
.narrow .dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, then this is what you want to add the following style:

```
.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelect{
  width: 240px;
}
```