# Set width to dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was trying to set the style of a dojox form CheckedMultiSelect control. First I tried to use the .set method. The physical width has changed, but the control is still automatically sized to the max. length of dropdown items.Second, I tried the way from this post -[How to set width to dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046335/how-to-set-width-to-dojox-form-checkedmultiselect). And it didn't do anything.

```js
var groupCheckedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect ({
      id: "groupChkMultiSelect",
      dropDown: true,
      multiple: true,
      class: 'narrow',
      label: "Group"
  }, 'GroupDiv');

groupCheckedMultiSelect.set('style', {width: '100px', height: '30px', fontSize: '14px'});
groupCheckedMultiSelect.startup();
```

```css
.narrow .dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Setting

```
.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectButton{
    width:400px
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/4L3sksmt/1/

Comment: wow! I have been tried a few ways and none of them worked. Your solution worked like a charm!